# textFieldShouldReturn not firing in iPad app

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, storyboard

I have an iPad app created using XCode 4 with Storyboard.  I have a UITableViewController with the interface defined as such:

```
@interface CustomerViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

In the .m file, I have a code snippet as:

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField  {

if(textField == businessName)  {
    [email becomeFirstResponder];
    return true;
}
```

The method 'textFieldShouldReturn' does NOT get executed.  What else needs to be done?  (BTW... I have never been able to get this to work in a iPad app, but always successful in a iPhone app)

Comment: Are you setting the businessName delegate to your class?

Comment: In the textFieldShouldReturn method, you're testing if the textField is equal to businessName. I'm assuming that's a UITextField object, but you have to set the delegate to receive callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the textFieldShouldReturn method, you're testing if the textField is equal to businessName. I'm assuming that's a UITextField object, but you have to set the delegate to receive callbacks. Just a simple self.businessName.delegate = self; when you create the TextField.

Another tip, I'd recommend calling it something like businessNameTextField. It's easier to read throughout your code.

Comment: Got it!  I see what all of you are now saying... I just checked again, and I do indeed set the final textfield in the iPhone app... thank you so much...

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the view controller as the delegate of the text field, just declaring that you conform to the protocol isn't enough. If it works in the iPhone but not iPad, then the chances are you haven't linked the delegate outlet in the iPad storyboard, but you have in the iPhone.

Comment: I'm confused... so, for each of the textFields (and there are 11 of them), I have to set each to a delegate?  How do I do that using Storyboards?  And I don't remember doing anything like this for the iPhone app...

Comment: Control-drag from the text field to your view controller (the yellow circle at the bottom), and choose the delegate outlet.

Comment: This is using Storyboard.. there is no NIB, and there is no yellow circle.  I just checked my iPHone app, and it also uses Storyboard, and I didn't do any of this to get it to work... do you think it's a bug with the code generation for the iPad?